# jqPlot custom tick labels

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I've got data with X values from 0 to 55. I would like to see these values as a custom text in tick labels. Ideally, I want to specify some callback, like

```
function tickLabel(tickValue) {
    return "This is " + tickValue;
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've found a solution.

```
xaxis: {
  tickRenderer: $.jqplot.AxisTickRenderer,
  tickOptions: {
    formatter: function(format, value) { return "This is " + value; } 
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems the best general-purpose answer, but I have found two corner-cases to be aware of: (1) it may not work with DateAxisRenderer; (2) should you need to output a label specific to the context of one plot on a page of multiple plots, a formatter will not have this context.  In either of these non-standard cases, I would advise monkey-patching jQuery.jqplot.DateTickFormatter or jQuery.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer.prototype.draw (either via replacement or via wrapping the calls), depending upon what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Use something like:

```
var line1 = [['This is '.$value, $value], ...]
```

And call your plot as:

```
var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1], {
    title: 'Title of your plot',
    series:[{renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer}],
    axesDefaults: {
        tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer ,
        tickOptions: {
          angle: -30,
          fontSize: '10pt'
        }
    },
    axes: {
      xaxis: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
      }
    }
  });
```