# p:chart long labels not wrapping

Tags: primefaces, jqplot

I am trying to draw a bar chart using PrimeFaces. I can draw the chart properly but  problem is variables in the x-axis could be too long.I want display next line if more than one word.How can I achieve this .Please help me out.

Comment: I added a relevant tag and improved your title. PF chart has the extender functionality. Try to search on jqplot on how to wrap long labels and use that via the extender

Comment: So it works fine for line charts?

Comment: I have tried extender extender function still I am not getting wrap long label.Please post example code if you have sample. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: But what did you try? And no, sorry, I don't have any example

Comment: I am tried bellow code ,still not achieve wrap text labels .                                                                                                              function my_ext() {
        this.cfg.axes.xaxis = {
        min:0,
        max:100,
        tickInterval:10 ,
        tickOptions:{
            formatString : '%02d'

            }
        };
       
    }

Comment: but what **does** happen if you use this...

Comment: To emphasizeThis is *all* jqplot related...Nothing PF can do about it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263551/jqplot-custom-tick-labels (or rotate the labels)

Comment: I have tried following code still I am not wrap the data.                 //#include  function my_ext() {
        this.cfg.axes = { 
   yaxis: {
    numberTicks: 10,
    labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
    labelOptions: { fontFamily: 'Verdana', fontSize: '8pt' },
   },
   xaxis: { 
    renderer:$.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
    rendererOptions: {
     tickRenderer:$.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer 
     },
    labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
    labelOptions: { fontFamily: 'Verdana', fontSize: '8pt' }
   }
  }; 
    }  //

Comment: why did you expect this to wrap the labels?

Comment: In my bar chart labels are too long its looking not good so user wants to wrap the label for every word.

Comment: Yes that is the basic problem, but based on what part of your last posted code did you expect it to work

Comment: I am new to Jqflot related things .I just google it and found some label warping code and tried through extension java-script function of prime faces chart.If you think any thing on this please let me know I will do that or any other solution.